# How to reference in Extjs in a view one of two stores with the same name?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, store, extjs4.2

I have two stores:

> Files@APP.store.aaa
>
> Files@APP.store.bbb

And two views

> List@APP.view.bbb
>
> List@APP.view.aaa

In each of them I want to reference different Files store. If I put only 'Files' in the views store property

> store: 'Files'

then I get the same store in both cases.
Putting 'Files@APP.store.bbb' doesn't work.

How should I reference them to get the proper store in the second view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because of a ExtJS MVC convetion which will do the following:

Split up the FQN by '@' and use the first part as storeId which will override any storeId that is predefined. The MVC is expecting each store to be singleton and don't take credit of any additional namespace if you use the @ syntax that way.

Try to register the stores (views/models) like

```
stores:['aaa.Files','bbb.Files']
```

ExtJS will now take care of the namespace but you will need to use it!

So the storeId are now: 'aaa.Files' and 'bbb.Files' which.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Maybe I'm missing something more? I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffered' of undefined ext-all.js:21"

Comment: @szym This error comes because a grid (or anything similiar) is configured with a invalid store... have you changed `store: 'Files'` to `store: 'aaa.Files'` or `store: 'bbb.Files'` ?

Comment: I tried few different combinations, nothing seems to work.
Now I have `stores: ['aaa.Files'],` in the controller and `store: ['aaa.Files'],` in the view. And this error in the console
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined ext-all.js:21

Comment: @szym There's a error: While `stores` should be a array `store` need to be either a store config, store instance or storeId. You can always  test if a store instance exist by typing `Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('aaa.Files')` into the console where the argument here is a storeId.